# Create node display custom tab

Tags: users, routes

I'm trying to create tab in node display that links to node delete form. I used hook_menu_local_tasks_alter in template.php

```
function mytheme_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
// Add a tab linking to node/add to all pages.
$data ['tabs'][0]['output'][] = array(
'#theme' => 'menu_local_task',
'#link' => array(
    'title' => t('Delete'),
    'tab_parent' => 'node/%',
    'tab_root' => 'node/%',
    'tab_root_href' => 'node/'.arg(1),
    'tab_parent_href' => 'node/'.arg(1),
    'href' => 'node/'.arg(1).'/delete',
    'access callback' => 'node_access',
    'access arguments' => array('delete', 1),
    'localized_options' => array(
    'attributes' => array(
     'title' => t('Delete'),
    ),
  ),
),

);

}
```

Tab is created but it is displayed for every user and on every page where tabs are enabled. How can I configure `access arguments` to display tab only on node display page and only for user with permissions `[Content type]: delete own content`?

Answer (score 0):

This will be done by [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), See the example below for creating tabs (MENU_LOCAL_TASK). This is how tabs will be created.

```
    // For the default local task, we need very little configuration, as the
  // callback and other conditions are handled by the parent callback.
  $items['examples/menu_example/tabs/default'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'title' => 'Default primary tab',
    'weight' => 1,
  );
  // Now add the rest of the tab entries.
  foreach (array(
    t('second') => 2,
    t('third') => 3,
    t('fourth') => 4,
  ) as $tabname => $weight) {
    $items["examples/menu_example/tabs/$tabname"] = array(
      'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
      'title' => $tabname,
      'page callback' => '_menu_example_menu_page',
      'page arguments' => array(t('This is the tab "@tabname" in the "basic tabs" example', array('@tabname' => $tabname))),
      'access callback' => TRUE,

      // The weight property overrides the default alphabetic ordering of menu
      // entries, allowing us to get our tabs in the order we want.
      'weight' => $weight,
    );
```